# How do we connect Spring WebClient to a Unix Domain Socket?

Tags: spring, docker, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Spring's WebClient underlyingly uses Netty which access to Unix domain sockets.  I am trying to make it access `/var/run/docker.sock` so that I can perform operations using the API as I need `/services` which is not supported by the docker-java library.

My current workaround is to create a socat container that exposes the Docker socket to TCP within an internal network which in turn allows me to use WebClient's HTTP connections.

Though come to think of it, having this workaround gives one benefit of not needing to put a larger Java application on the manager node.

However, I am still curious how to connect to the unix domain docket.

Comment: I too am curious if this is a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Netty HttpClient [following their documentation regarding Unix Domain Sockets here.](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_unix_domain_sockets_4)

```
import io.netty.channel.unix.DomainSocketAddress;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;

HttpClient client = HttpClient.create()
                              .remoteAddress(() -> new DomainSocketAddress("/var/run/docker.sock"));
```

Then you can tell WebClient to use this HttpClient like this.

```
WebClient.builder()
         .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(client))
         .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can expose the docker daemon over TCP and use the REST API.

Comment: that's what I did (second paragraph re my workaround), I am trying to avoid that